# How to reset a function variable every n times?

Tags: c++, variables, static

I'm using a random number generating function and it's working fine but I need to reset a function variable **nSeed** every **n** times, let's say **nSeed=5323** .. how can i return it to it's starting value **5323** every **5** operations i'm not sure how to do it .. here's an example:

```
unsigned int PRNG()  

{  
    static unsigned int nSeed = 5323;  
    nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403);  
    return nSeed  % 32767;
}  

int main()
{
   int count=0;  
   while(count<10)  
   {  
       count=count+1;  
       cout<<PRNG()<<endl;  

          if(count==5)
          {  
               nSeed= 5323;   //here's the problem, "Error nSeed wasn't declared in the scoop"
          } 
   }  
}
```

**Note** : I need to declare the counter in the scoop, not in the function.

Comment: Its only a problem because `nSeed` is not visible in the current scope.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @drescherjm exactly, i don't know how to connect the **nSeed** in the function to the **nSeed** in the scoope, the error i get is ** Error the nSeed wasn't declared in the scoop**

Comment: I think vlad has a good approach.

Comment: I think mine is better! So much complexity here for 5 repeating numbers!

Comment: @Bathsheba good point.

Comment: But the matter is i can't declare the counter in the function since it's a variable in the scoop, it's not constant **5**, it can be 5,8,15..etc , so the nSeed needs to be connected to a counter declared in the scoop not the function !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use another static variable. For example

```
unsigned int PRNG()  
{
    const unsigned int INITIAL_SEED = 5323;
    static unsigned int i;
    static unsigned int nSeed;

    if ( i++ % 5 == 0 ) 
    {
        nSeed = INITIAL_SEED;
        i = 1;
    }

    nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403);

    return nSeed  % 32767;
}
```

Another way is to declare the function with a parameter. For example

```
unsigned int PRNG( bool reset )  
{
    const unsigned int INITIAL_SEED = 5323;
    static unsigned int nSeed = INITIAL_SEED;

    if ( reset ) nSeed = INITIAL_SEED;

    nSeed = (8253729 * nSeed + 2396403);

    return nSeed  % 32767;
}
```

Comment: Very picky but you ought to address the issue when `i` wraps round. A power of 2 never ends in a 5 so you'll always have a bug,

Comment: Thanks. You've improved your answer with the fix, and I've ruined mine! Have an upvote!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But the matter is i can't declare the counter in the function since it's a variable in the scoop, it's not constant 5 it dependes on many equations in the scoop so it have to declared in the scoop, it can be 5,8,15..etc , so the nSeed needs to be connected to a counter declared in the scoop not the function !!

Comment: @drescherjm it doesn't work proberly, it gives the first output repeated 10 times

Comment: @johnshreef It depends on how you call the function.

Comment: Oh. Sorry.It's early in the morning for me (and I am not a morning person). It should be `cout<<PRNG(count % 5 == 0)<<endl;` You could also do the increment when you count like this `cout<<PRNG(count++ % 5 == 0)<<endl;`

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm

Answer (score 3):

If you're only using 5 draws from this generator in a cycle then refactor the whole thing to

```
int PRNG[5] = {5323, /*ToDo - you work out the other 4 elements*/};
```

and at the call site use

```
cout << PRNG[count % 5] << endl;
```

else your code will end up looking like something worthy of submission to an obfuscation contest.

You'll need to take steps to avoid a bump when `count` wraps round to zero. assuming you'll ever reach that point. Perhaps set `count` to zero when it reaches 5? Or, for I can't resist, start with `count = 4`, and use

```
cout << PRNG[++count %= 5] << endl;
```

nothing that this piece of devilry `++count %= 5` doesn't compile in C!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `count == 5`, use the modulo operator:

```
if (count % 5 == 0)
{
    nSeed= 5323;
}
```

This will reset the value every time count is divisible by `5`, which will happen once every five iterations since you are incrementing by `1`.

---

As pointed out in comments, you also need to make sure that the variable is in scope.

Comment: thanks But that doesn't reset the nSeed value in the function, which is what i need here.